# javascript alert box with radio buttons

Tags: javascript

I want to create an alert box with 3 radio buttons in it. It should be like

'Replace'
'Save'
'Merge'

along with OK and Cancel buttons. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to what WoLpH said, you specifically want a modal overlay that can be called programmatically similar to an alert box. Give [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) or [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/overlay/) a try.

Answer (score 3):

There is no default javascript box that does this, you have `confirm()`, `prompt` and `alert` available and that's it.

There are however widgetsets/libraries that give you this option. Try [Ext JS](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/message-box/msg-box.html) for example

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to create modal dialog box with the controls you would like to show. You can customize the look & get rid of the default grey dialog boxes, it's really cool. Check the link below.

[Javascript modal dialog sample](http://devarchive.net/ajaxcontroltoolkit_modalpopup_control_confirmation_dialog.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

use the input tag to generate radio buttons

`<input type="radio" name="button_1">Replace</input>`

and div tag to generate you okay and cancel buttons

`<div id="cancel">Cancel</div>`

and have the onclick functions of your div's be a javascript call which pulls the data out of the radio buttons.