# How to display radio button on an alert box

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to have a radio button in an alert box? 
The requirement is, not to use any modal box, that why we just think if it's possible with alert box or confirm box. then we can good to go.

Any help will appreciate.
Sample Screenshot is below.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript alert box with radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467382/javascript-alert-box-with-radio-buttons)

Comment: No, that is of course not possible.

Comment: You should find the custom modal.

Comment: You can try html / js modal popup

Comment: You can't unless you realize modal is the solution (hence your requirements are barriers not constraints)

Comment: Thanks to all for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't guess. i know that this is in fact impossible.
the reason is simple:

`alert()`, `prompt()` aswell as `confirm()` were part of html + js since js exists.
they never got deprecated though they break the asyncronous flow of javascript.

this is essentially why they only allow you to play around with strings.
they were never intended to be feature rich.
they were actually invented out of the blue because the inventor (Brendan Eich) thought they'd come in handy. (wich at that time was more than enough for everyone)

they are by design blocking operations and should be avoided as much as possible.

to get around them simply create a so called modal dialog (thats basically a `<div>` with `position: fixed` above the pages content.

benefit:
you can easily make it appear as you want and you would not break any network connections or behavior of your application.

PS:
don't use w3schools as reference for learning or anything else.
they are a low quality database. you should look stuff up on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org) or other sites but should seriously avoid w3schools since it's not feature complete on any topic.
keep in mind this is an opinion.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gottz

Comment: to be honest there were some idea's to allow custom popup windows to create such functionality but it got deprecated due to abuse and the fact that theese windows also broke the asyncronous flow of javascript. (think about it as if you show such a popup and your whole page freezes)

Comment: if you look at single sign on popups of twitter etc. for example.. they do some other wizzardry that would require you to use either advanced not so supported techniques to communicate between tabs in your domain or do it like they do and make them state less by only using tokens... as i said.. heavy stuff. if you ever want to go that route you most likely did not find an inline way. (xss prevention etc.)

Comment: all in all a modal dialog should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to use radio inside of alert window.

Message parameter in `window.alert(message);` has a string type and you cannot put Object or HTML there  (will be transfomed to string).

Answer (score -1):

Do not overuse `window.prompt()` Method , as it prevents the user from accessing the other parts of the page until the box is closed.

[Window prompt Usage Note](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp)

Comment: Kindly read the question again..Questioner has requested for "using radio button in an alert box and requirement is , not to use any modal box..."   My answer describes as  "window object does provide alert , prompt and confirm method to display messages to end user.. However , w3schools has provided the description about do not overuse this window object methods... "

Comment: I pointed w3school tutorial as help to questioner to convey we can't use windows object method for given requirements.. Need to use jQuery-ui or other plugins..